# How to make my text next to checkbox not under it?

Tags: html, css

```css
.selected_area {
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
  padding-top:5px;
  height: 330px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width:233px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="selected_area">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="scooter" id=""><div class="label-text fa-lg"><span>ScooterScooterScooterScooterScooter ScooterScooterScooter cooterScooterScooterScooter ScooterScooterScooter</span></div>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="motorcycle" id=""><div class="label-text fa-lg"><span>Motorcycle</span></div>
              </label>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="downtown 250 en" id=""><div class="label-text fa-lg"><span>DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN) DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN)</span></div>
              </label>
            </div>
```

How to make my text next to checkbox not under it?

Comment: Don’t make a `<div>`. Why do you need the `<div>` anyway? You can remove it and put all `class`es associated to that `<div>` on the `<span>`.

Comment: i need set background-color to this div area.

Comment: To clarify: I mean the `div`s next to the checkboxes.

Comment: I will add a custom checkbox icon instead of original checkbox by label-text:before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you've to write `CSS` like:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.label-text {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  word-break: break-all; 
}
```

Also for side-by-side alignment you should use `<span>` instead of block elements like `<div>`.

I've created [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/0mc8ahha/1/), please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="selected_area">
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="scooter" id="">
        <span class="label-text fa-lg">
            <span>ScooterScooterScooterScooterScooter ScooterScooterScooter cooterScooterScooterScooter ScooterScooterScooter</span>
        </span>
        <br>
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="motorcycle" id="">
            Motorcycle

                <br>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="downtown 250 en" id="">
            DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN) DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN)

                    </label>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe so?

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.selected_area {
    background-color: #c8c8c8;
    padding:10px;
    height: 330px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:233px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.selected_area label {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: block;
}
.selected_area .label-text {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 24px;
}
.selected_area input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="selected_area">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="scooter" id="">
        <div class="label-text fa-lg"><span>ScooterScooterScooterScooter ScooterScooterScooter cooterScooterScooterScooter ScooterScooterScooter</span>

        </div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="motorcycle" id="">
        <div class="label-text fa-lg"><span>Motorcycle</span>

        </div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="downtown 250 en" id="">
        <div class="label-text fa-lg"><span>DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN) DOWNTOWN 250(EN)DOWNTOWN 250(EN)</span>

        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.label-text.fa-lg {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

check this link for more help on display property 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/